# Ajax/jQuery CORS file upload with IIS

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have a Java web app which has a requirement to upload files to a separate IIS server. I have full administrative control over both servers and the applications.

I am using the jQuery plugin for file uploads from blueimp (http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/)

Originally I had browser security problems since it was cross-domain, so I modified the IIS server to allow  the origin and so the initial OPTIONS request from the server which was failing before now succeeds.

Then comes the POST with the file data which is succeeding on the server side and streaming a response but the client keeps choking on it.

Using Google Chrome looking in the Network tab I see status "(canceled). If I click on the request and look at Preview/Response tabs they are empty. So no help there.

I then added a jQuery fail handler function on my fileupload call and placed a breakpoint in it to check the xhr object. It is useless, status 0, readyState 0, responseText is empty string and statusText is just "error". Great.

How the heck do I debug this problem where there is no indication of what is wrong?

I tried a separate test page where I used a standard HTML form to perform the upload to the same resource, and it worked fine. The response was received without any issues. So I am guessing it has something to do with CORS? But no idea what... I would figure if the OPTIONS request passed then there should not be a problem.

Here is my code for setting up fileupload call:

```
input.fileupload({
            dataType: 'text',   
            maxFileSize : 100000000,
            done: function (e, response) {
                debugger;
            },
            fail: function (a, b) {             
                debugger;
            }
        });
```

It always goes to the fail condition, and by digging through those paramters I can find the XHR object and find no helpful details on the cause of the error.

I tried both Chrome and Firefox, neither of them are working

I also originally tried dataType 'json' to no avail (I write the response from the server in JSON format, and thought maybe it was a parsing issue so switched to dataType text on both sides and still no progress)

Please help!